# Static integer in class not accessible in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, class, foreach, static

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    class Program
    {
        static StandardRoom room55 = new StandardRoom(55);
        static StandardRoom room45 = new StandardRoom(45);
        static List<StandardRoom> roomMap = new List<StandardRoom>() { room45, room55 };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(StandardRoom room in roomMap)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(room.roomId);   
        }
    }

class StandardRoom
{
    public static int roomId;

    public StandardRoom(int roomNum)
    {
        roomId = roomNum;
    }
}
```

My problem is:

> Member "room.roomId" cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

I'm really not sure how to fix this.

Comment: don't make it static.  Your implementation is saying that it needs to be on the instance.

Answer (score 5):

```
class StandardRoom
{
    public int roomId {get; set;} // modified
}
```

You do not want a static field here, you want a public instance property.

If you want to make sure it cannot be changed from outside the class then make the setter private or remove it completely which is fine for c# v6.

```
class StandardRoom
{
    public int roomId {get; private set;} // modified
    public StandardRoom(int roomNum)
    {
        this.roomid = roomNum;
    }
}
```

Now why not static? Static is a single instance tracked on the type itself. You want to define a roomid for every room instance so it has to be an instance variable. You should hardly ever use static fields / properties.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static keyword from the `roomId` field in `StandardRoom` class.

Comment: You mean remove it from the `roomId` field in `StandardRoom` because the class itself is not static.

Comment: @juharr Yes, that's what I meant. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

So basically If you have static member, you can use it by class name not by the object(logic: static members are shared accross all the objects), But if you have non static member, you should use it by object. So `RoomId` should not be static, it should be a public field.
You can make other changes too in `StandardRoom` class declaration. Like making it singlton, sealed or make properties only set, set or both, but it all depends on your requirement and application design.

Answer (score -1):

**Why you get the error:**

You're referencing the static value as though it were an instance value:

```
room.roomId
```

Instead, one would qualify a static value with a type name to reference it as a static value:

```
StandardRoom.roomId
```

Static members are associated with the type *itself*, not with any given instance of the type.

**What you should actually do:**

Looking more closely at your implementation, it seems *highly likely* that you meant for the value to actually be instance and not static:

```
public int roomId;
```

This is because your instance constructor is setting the value.  If it's a static value, any new instance of the object is going to change the value globally.  So *every* element in your `List<StandardRoom>` would appear to have the same value, whichever value was set last.

By making it an instance member instead of a static member, each instance would have its own value independent of other instances.

**Additionally:**

Since the value is public, in good form it should probably be a property instead of a field:

```
public int RoomId { get; set; }
```